# Is it more RESTful to create a resource with a JSON payload or regular POST parameters?

Tags: json, rest

I'm making an API & wondering whether to design a factory endpoint to take a JSON payload representing the attributes of the resource to be created, or regular application/x-www-form-urlencoded parameters in the request body, or whether it does not matter at all from a REST standpoint.

Comment: If you are returning data in JSON it would be more consistant to accept it in JSON as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's equally RESTful in either case. You're just using different formats (representations). No format is intrinsically more RESTful than the other.

Comment: Agree with this. This is why http has Accept and Content-Type in the header so you can send and receive whatever you want.